# executing a javascript function within a function

Tags: javascript, scope, kineticjs, local-variables

This question refers to kineticJS but the problem is about the basic logic of nested functions I believe. I have a kineticjs stage on a div:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

The kineticjs script puts a shape on the stage:

```
function displayVizualization(){
    //SKETCH SIZE
    var SKETCH_WIDTH = 800;
    var SKETCH_HEIGTH = 800;


    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: document.getElementById('container'),
        width: SKETCH_WIDTH,
        height: SKETCH_HEIGTH
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 239,
        y: 75,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(rect);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    function updateViz(){
        console.log("we are in the updateViz function")
        var count = document.getElementById("formID:counter").value;
        console.log("count is: "+count);
        rect.transitionTo({
            x: 100*count,
            duration: 2,
            easing: easing
        });
    }
}
```

I need to call the function "updateViz" from another script on this page in an oncomplete attribute. I have something that says:

```
oncomplete: updateViz();
```

But of course I get an "function not defined" error because updateViz() is nested in displayVizualization().

How should I call updateViz() then? Thx!

[EDIT: moving updateViz() outside displayVisualization() is perfectly fine with me. But then please explain how the variables in updateViz should refer to the variables in displayVisualization?]

Comment: Can't you just move the `updateViz` function outside of the `displayVizualisation` function? Also, IIRC you should do `oncomplete: updateViz` (note the missing ())

Comment: @Martin: `updateVis` closes over `rect`, so it can't just be moved. Things could be refactored, but it's more complicated than just moving the function out a level.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, correct. I would make it into a class personally

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: could you be more specific about this class solution? That would really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the above snippet is loaded as a separate js file, you can assign a variable to the container function and return a reference to your function

```
var displayVizualization = function (){
...
return { updateViz:updateViz }
}
```

Now you can call this function updateViz using

```
displayVizualization.updateViz()
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't, unless you modify `displayVisualization` to return a reference to the `updateViz` within it (or more significant refactoring). This is because there isn't **one** `updateViz` function, there's one *for each call* to `displayVisualization`. They refer to ("close over") different references to `rect`*, where the `rect` in question depends on the call.

Let's use a simpler example:

```
function foo(n) {
    setTimeout(bar, 1000);

    function bar() {
        console.log(n);
    }
}
foo(10);
foo(20);
```

What happens with the code above? You clearly know your stuff, so the answer is that the first call to `foo` sets up a delayed function call that will happen a second later and log "10" to the console. The second call sets up logging "20".

But why? Because there is no *one* `bar` function: A `bar` function is created each time we call `foo`, and refers to the execution context in which it was created (the context created by the call to `foo`).

If you modified `displayVisualization` to return a reference to `updateViz`, then you could use that return value to call `updateViz`, because it would refer to each function as appropriate.

---

(I should mention that most modern JavaScript engines won't actually duplicate the *code* for `bar`, they'll just create multiple function objects that refer to the same underlying code with a different execution context pointer. But that's an implementation detail.)

---

* Technically, they don't close over different `rect` references, they close over something called an *execution context* which contains `rect` amongst other things. More about closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)